# Angular ng-selected by value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reference

I am using AngularJS with an select element. I'm using ng-model, ng-options and ng-selected. My only problem is that ng-selected calls it by reference and not by value.

```
<select class="faiconselect"
        ng-model="serie.meter"
        ng-options="(m.SelectBoxName) for m in serie.meterList"
        ng-selected="m.Id== serie.Id && m.readingType == serie.readingType"
    ng-change="serie.changeMeter()">
</select>
```

I simply want to compare if a value of m equals a value of serie.

Is there a way to make ng-selected use call by value, and not call by reference?

Comment: Can you show what serie.meterList looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-selected does not apply to a select element, it applies to an option element.  I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but you probably want to determine which element you want to be selected in your controller and then assign serie.meter there.

For example:

```
angular.forEach($scope.serie.meterList, function(value, key){        
    if(value.Id == $scope.serie.Id && value.readingType == $scope.serie.readingType)
    {
        $scope.serie.meter = value;
    }
});
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ridupuvo/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Better way to compare m and serie in the controller. and set

```
$scope.serie.meter
```

with needed value.